# Datagridview manual column assignments appear in wrong column

Tags: vb.net, winforms, datagridview

I have populated a `dataagridview` using an `SqlDataAdapter` dataset and manually assigned fields from the dataset to manually created columns in the `datagridview`.  I'm experiencing something odd, in that for `DatagridView.Columns(1)`, which I assigned as `DatagridView.Columns(1).DataPropertyName = "Description"`, when the grid populates the value from `DatagridView.Columns(2).DataPropertyName = "Vers"`, as so:

[image: Wrongly populated value in DataGridView]

Even more perplexing is that `datagridview` has a `SelectionChanged` event which populates a textbox with `Me.SelectedDescription.Text = DatagridView.SelectedRows(0).Cells(1).Value.ToString`, which correctly displays the description:

[image: Description correctly populates]

I'm perplexed as to why the `Vers`value is showing in the `Description` column in the `datagridview` therefore? This looks like a bug to me or do I need some form of workaround?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, solved:

I had a hidden column between columns 0 and 1, viewable in the Edit Columns dialog. I needed to move this down to the correct location in the list.